# Access denied for user MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, localhost

The problem is my localhost Laravel project just won't connect to MySQL, I get the following error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

OS: macos high sierra 
Browser: Chrome; 
MySql version: 8.0.12
Laravel version: 5.6 
Homestead Version: 7.0

Things I have tried to fix it:

1. Checked that there is an instance of MySql running - It's running.
2. Check the credentials in the .env file and config/database.php - The credentials are correct (Mysql root user password has been change from the one generated on installation)
3. I checked if I could connect via terminal to double check that the credentials are correct  - I can and they are correct
4. Tried creating a new MySql user with all root privileges. - same error.
5. I can run `php artisan migrate` in  the terminal and the tables are created. which I thought was strange as the site is denied.
6. I completely removed MySql 3 times.  (following this guide: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d) - same error
7. So then I started from the beginning destroyed the vagrant box and Laravel project and started from the beginning  - Same error.
8. Fought the urge to punch my computer.

.env (Updated)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: site.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/sitetest/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

/etc/hosts

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##


127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 site.test
```

Comment: Do you have a mysql user named 'root' and password matches? And database name ?

Comment: If your credentials are true try to change db name to another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the hosts file, when running Homestead, you'll have to change `127.0.0.1 site.test` to `192.168.10.10 site.test`

Of course that will only work after `vagrant up`

Comment: Can you explain why this does what it does?

Comment: Did it work? Well, when you run vagrant, you starting up a virtual machine on top of your windows, in this case Linux. To access it a the vm has its own local ip. In the case of homestead (homestead.yalm file), this is set to 192.168.10.10. To access it you run `ssh -p 7822 ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` password 'vagrant' (no quotes)

Comment: You may wonder how you access the vm through 127.0.0.1. You are creating a tunneled connection to the vm. It's the only way to access the vm. As both laravels are an exact copy while vagrant runs, it explains why locally run artisan commands have an effect on the vm files. And visa versa.

Comment: FYI, if you use a MySQL client like MySQL Workshop you can access your vm database by just adding a '0'. Your sql connection becomes 127.0.0.1 port 33060.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had already solved the issue, but your answer explained why it happened in the first place. Update your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

The default password for homestead is not `something`.

According to laravel docs it is `secret`.

> A homestead database is configured for both MySQL and PostgreSQL out
>   of the box. For even more convenience, Laravel's .env file configures
>   the framework to use this database out of the box.
>
> To connect to your MySQL or PostgreSQL database from your host
>   machine's database client, you should connect to 127.0.0.1 and port
>   33060 (MySQL) or 54320 (PostgreSQL). The username and password for
>   both databases is homestead / secret.

Docs at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

#### Update:

You can also grant your user the permissions to play with the database with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I've tried this as well and gave the error ` Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist` and it does exist as does the user in mysql and it has permissions.

Comment: You simply need to grant permissions to your user to play with your table then and should be good to go.

Comment: I have tried that before and tried it again. ran `GRANT ALL ON homestead.users TO 'homestead'@'localhost';` as the root user. same error as above  `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist`

Comment: The Grant query should look like this:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';

Comment: Unfortunately, same error.  So I Initialised database and created the homestead user, database and tables from the beginning and still go the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by caching your config:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Tried that too. as well as `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan cache:clear` getting the same error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

1. Cd into your Homestead directory
2. run `vagrant ssh`
3. run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: This may have solved your problem, but it's not the solution.

Comment: I think, your problem was that you have 2 different Laravel configurations on your machine - one local and the other with vagrant. If you have vagrant and homestead configured, you don't need to install MySQL separately. So when you were unsuccessfully trying all the commands, you were actually trying them on the host machine. Later when you logged in to the guest machine, via `vagrant ssh`, everything started working properly.

Comment: If my comment has helped you identify the problem, please let me know, so I may convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

first inside in mysql run `sudo mysql -u root -p`
next execute this command :

```
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User="root";
flush priviliges;
exit
```